# Is it bad practice to have nested render loops?

Tags: c++

I'm porting a game from Ruby to C++. There is a main render loop that updates and draw the content. Now let's say that during the game, you want to select an item another screen. The way it's done in the original code is to do `Item item = getItemFromMenu();` `getItemFromMenu` is a function that will open the menu and do have its own update/render loop, which mean that during the whole time the player has this other screen open, you are in a nested render loop. I feel like this is a bad method but I'm not sure why. On the other hand it's very handy because I can open the menu with just 1 function call and so the code is localized.
Any idea if this is a bad design or not?
I hesitated to post it on gamedev, but since this is mostly a design issue I posted it here

edit : some pseudo-code to give you an idea:

The usual loop in the main part of the code:

```
while(open) {
   UpdateGame();
   DrawGame();
}
```

now inside UpdateGame() i would do something like:

```
if(keyPressed == "I") {
   Item& item = getItemFromInventory();
}
```

And `getItemFromInventory()`:

```
 while(true) {
    UpdateInventory();

    if(item_selected) return item;
    DrawInventory();
 }
```

Comment: I've been struggling with a similar reality in a VB.NET application that performs `DoEvents` in a "progress window" kind-of rendering loop to keep the GUI from freezing and crashing and dying but to also avoid the nastiness of introducing threads. It means that only one of my progress windows will get updated at a time. I don't really mind, and it _works_, and it avoids threads. But it feels nasty. I left it for now...

Comment: One bad thing I could see with this is the possible duplicate code in all the places where you have such a game loop, depending on how it's done.

Comment: Could you show pseudocode for what you have in mind?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You can also avoid threads and avoid blocking at the same time by making use of GUI dispatch loop. For example, do one step at a time and schedule another step while loop is also re-painting GUI as needed.. No? Though it is a lot more complicated than creating some background worker thread.

Comment: @Vlad: Not sure I get the "schedule another step" part.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You can always split your algorithm into steps. Say, step A, step B and step C. Then you can execute step A and schedule step B to be performed through the GUI dispatch loop. It's like asynchronous programming using GUI dispatch loop as event notification mechanism.

Comment: @Vlad: Meh, effort. Not to mention far-reaching code changes for a single feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If you've looked at the new Async CTP for .NET, the new `Async` keyword does this (scheduling something for later) for you with almost no effort on your part.

Comment: @RonWarholic: Worth remembering, ta!

Answer (score 2):

A good way to handle something like this would be to replace the `DrawInventory()` call with something like `InvalidateInventory()`, which will mark the current graphical state of the inventory as outdated and request it to be redrawn during the next frame rendering (which'll happen pretty soon after when the main loop gets to `DrawGame()`).

This way, you can keep running through the main loop, but the only parts of the screen that get looked at for redrawing are the ones that have been invalidated, and during normal gameplay you can invalidate your (2/3)D environment as a normal part of processing, but then inside the inventory you can always mark only inventory assets as needing to be redrawn, which minimises overhead.

The other part of your inner loop, `UpdateInventory()`, can be a part of `UpdateGame()` if you use a flag to indicate the current game state, something like:

```
UpdateGame()
{
    switch(gameState)
    {
        case INVENTORY:
            UpdateInventory();
            break;

        case MAIN:
        default:
            UpdateMain();
            break;
    }
}
```

If you really wanted, you could also apply this to drawing:

```
DrawGame()
{
    switch(gameState)
    {
        case INVENTORY:
            DrawInventory();
            break;

        case MAIN:
        default:
            DrawMain();
            break;
    }
}
```

But I think drawing should be encapsulated and you should tell it which part of the screen, rather than which separate area of the game, needs to be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

What you've created with your nested render loop is functionally a state machine (as most game render loops tend to be).  The problem with the nested loop is that many times you'll want to do the same sorts of things in your nested loop as your outer loop (process input, handle IO, update debug info etc).

I've found that it's better to have one render loop and use a finite state machine (FSM) to represent your actual states.  Your states might look like:

- Main menu state
- Options menu state
- Inventory state
- World view state

You hook up transitions between states to move between them. The player clicking a button might trigger the transition which could play an animation or otherwise, then move to the new state.  With a FSM your loop might look like:

```
while (!LeaveGame()) {
  input = GetInput();
  timeInfo = GetTimeInfo();

  StateMachine.UpdateCurrentState(input, timeInfo);
  StateMachine.Draw();
}
```

A full FSM can be a bit heavyweight for a small game so you can try a simplified state machine using a stack of game states.  Every time the user does an action to transition to a new state you push the state on a stack.  Likewise when they leave a state you pop it off.  Only the top of the stack typically receives input and the other items on the stack may/may not draw (depending on your preference).  This is a common approach and has some upsides and downsides depending on who you talk to.

The simplest option of all is to just throw a switch statement in to pick which render function to use (similar to darvids0n's answer).  If you're writing an arcade clone or a small puzzle game that would do just fine.